# The temperature at a point x, y on a flat metal plate is given by T( x, y)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The temperature at a point x, y on a flat metal plate is given by $T(x,y)= \frac{81}{ \sqrt{1+4x^2 + y^2} }$

Find the rate of change of the temperature at the point ( 1, 2) if one moves in a straight line toward the origin.

for this question do i just take the derivative of the function then plug in (0,0)since it said toward the origin,

Comment: No, you find the directional derivative at the point $(1,2)$ in the direction of the origin $(0,0)$. As a hint the vector pointing from $(1,2)$ to the origin is $\langle -1, -2 \rangle$. The directional derivative of a function $F(x,y)$ at a point $(x_0, y_0)$ in a direction $\vec{v}$ is given by $\nabla F(x_0, y_0) \cdot \vec{v}$

Comment: so (x0,y0) should be (1,2) i guess. what about the ∇F?

Comment: I'm assuming you've already learned how to find the gradient of a function $\nabla F \equiv \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\hat{i} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}\hat{j}$

Comment: not really im doing self study. this part is really hard. so sorry to ask again whats the i and j?

Comment: @LuoBobby They are the unit vectors of the $x$ and $y$ directions. You should read about vectors before studying multivariate calculus.

Comment: just found out the ∇F, do you guys mind how to find rate of change?

Comment: Then the rate is the dot product between $\nabla F$ and the unit vector that points from (1,2) to (0,0). You shall get some resource such as a textbook or Paul's online math notes to see how it works.